# Is it possible for location= prior to onload to always create a new item in history?

Tags: javascript, events, redirect, html5-history

I'm using the Intent URI to open an Android application from a web page.

User is viewing `example.net/unpaid`

User clicks Charge next to item to be paid.

The browser navigates to `example.net/charge?ref=...`
which outputs:

```
<script>location='intent:... my android payment app ...'</script>
<a href="javascript:history.back()">click here to return</a>
```

This launches the application on Android.

However, the browser sees this as a redirect (i.e. `location.replace`), because the `location=` line occurs prior to the `load` event.

Since there is no item in the back button history, Android assumes the 'app open' replaces the `/charge` page.

So in the background, the `/unpaid` page is sitting there.

This means when the user completes the payment, the `/unpaid` page will be out of date because it was loaded too early.

One way to solve this problem is to use

```
<script>
  onload=function() {
    setTimeout(function () {
      location = ...
    }, 1}
  }
</script>
```

But it got me thinking.. Is there a way to get a new entry in the 'back' history, without having to wait for the `load` event to be fired?